# If all radioisotopes in the human body decayed at once?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, thought-experiment

Let's suppose that - in the quantum randomness of nuclear decay - the Carbon-14 and Potassium-40 atoms inside an adult human were to all undergo decay at once, or within an extremely short amount of time like 1/100th of a second.

What would be the result? How much radiation would people nearby be exposed to? How much of this energy would be released as just penetrating ionizing radiation and how much would be dumped directly into the decaying person's body? Would it be enough for it to catch fire? Explode? If so, how big of an explosion?

Comment: What have you done to estimate it?

Comment: This is really a statistical mechanics question, akin to “what would happen if a random density fluctuation put all of the air molecules in the left half of a room?” It’s probably more interesting to estimate the waiting time before such a fluctuation than to spitball counterfactually about its consequences.

Comment: @rob - well, it was interesting enough for me to do a back-of-the-envelope calculation.